# How to debug "array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given" in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel

I'm learning Laravel, and still a lot to learn. Been practising lately, and now im a situation where I want in the same page to make a query of the table "robots" based on a choice of a category and then if I want, make a new query based on that choice AND adding a price range choice. But its getting a error: "array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given". I don't even know exactly where is the error.

The Laravel version is 5.4. The tables in this case are: robots, categories

This is the code:

controller

```
function catalog(Request $request) {
    $categories = DB::table('categories')->pluck('Category', 'id');
    $categoryesc = $request->categoryesc;
    $robots = DB::table('robots')->where('Category_id', $categoryesc)->get();
    $priceesc = $request->priceesc;
    $robots2 = DB::table('robots')->where('Category_id', $categoryesc AND 'Price', '<=', $priceesc)->get();
    return view('catalog', compact('robots', 'categories'));
}
```

Catalog.php

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
@include('header')

<main>
<h1>Catalog</h1>

<div>Choose the category</div>
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'GET')) !!}
    {!! Form::select('categoryesc', ['Category', $categories],  array('onchange' => 'chcat()')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}

<div>Choose the price</div>
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'GET')) !!}
    {!! Form::selectRange('priceesc', 100, 200, 300, 400, 500,  array('onchange' => 'chpri()')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}

<div>Choose the model</div>
<b>On this page ({{ $robots->count() }} robots)</b>

<div id="area1">
@foreach($robots as $robot)
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'RobotController@orders', 'method' =>  'GET')) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('modelesc', $robot->Model) !!}
{!! Form::submit($robot->Model) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
</div>

<div id="area2">
@foreach($robots2 as $robot2)
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'RobotController@orders', 'method' =>  'GET')) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('modelesc', $robot->Model) !!}
{!! Form::submit($robot->Model) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
</div>

</main>
```

layout.blade (where I place the jQuery)

```
        $('#categoryesc').on('change', function chcat(){
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
        });

        $('#priceesc').on('change', function chpri(){
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
        });
```

Comment: I dont see any array_key_exists() in your code. Please revise the code-snippet

Answer (score 0):

This query is what's causing the error:

```
$robots2 = DB::table('robots')->where('Category_id', $categoryesc AND 'Price', '<=', $priceesc)->get();
```

You need to make each `where` it's own method like:

```
$robots2 = DB::table('robots')->where('Category_id', $categoryesc)->where('Price', '<=', $priceesc)->get();
```

They will chain together with `AND` automatically behind the scenes unless you use `orWhere()` or you use it like `where('Price', '<=', $priceesc, 'or')`

Comment: I edited the code. Now its giving the error: "Illegal operator and value combination"

Comment: Looks like you have 2 forms there which means when you submit one then you're not pulling the input from the other and depending on which one `$request->categoryesc;` or `$priceesc = $request->priceesc;` is null and you're not able to use a `where('Price', '<=', null)` which is most likely what is causing your error.